# Compile IronPython with Mono

Tags: c#, mono, ironpython

When I try to install IronPython on Debian with Mono (3.12), I get the following error:

```
socket.cs(1900,63): error CS0117: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName' does not contain a definition for `IPv6Only'
```

How can I solve this problem? According to [the IronPython website](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/wiki/Building#wiki_building-mono), everything should compile without errors.

In the Mono mailing list there is [already such a bug](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/System-Net-Sockets-SocketOptionName-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-IPv6Only-td4665423.html), but there is no answer to this bug. Therefore I thought that maybe this forum is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on either IronPython or Mono, but out of curiosity I just tried this.

For whatever reason, the `IPV6Only` value in the `SocketOptionName` `enum` appears to be missing in the Mono implementation.  The error message you're getting is from the code in `IronPython.Module/Socket.cs` attempting to reference this.  It turns out that this is already recognised in the codebase as a feature that not all platforms have, so there's an easy workaround:

The `Common.proj` project file in the `Solutions/` directory in your git checkout defines a number of possible `ReferencedPlatform` values.  The default value is `V4`.  Just below there in the XML, find a block starting:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ReferencedPlatform)' == 'V4'">
```

Nested in there is a Features element with a list of the features that apply, and if you find and delete `FEATURE_IPV6` at the end of the list, then you should find that the project will build using `make`.  I briefly tried firing up the `ipy.exe` that is generated and it seems to work.

Obviously this isn't a very good solution. Probably the best thing would be to file a bug report with the IronPython project.  I guess that Mono on Linux is probably a fairly low priority for the guys who are working to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, up to mono 4.0 throws `Protocol option not supported` when setting `IPv6Only` false.

This is probably resolved here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-4.2.0-branch/mono/metadata/socket-io.c#L536

But do note the compile flag `IPV6_V6ONLY`

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? Are you saying that if I add some text to the `xbuild` command, that it will compile? If so, what is that text?

Comment: I am using mono 4.2.1, and if I attempt to build without removing the `IPV6Only` feature from `Common.proj`, it still fails.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not tried 4.2, I just spotted the code change that implies it might work soon